# Running a method using web.py on Apache2 as soon as the script loads

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I'm trying to run a scheduler as soon as web.py script starts which is being hosted on apache2 using mod_wsgi but it's not working.

Tried calling the function in the **main** and also added it as a global function but in vain.

If I put the code inside a class it works but then on each apache service restart I would have to hit the scheduler start API.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     #for local testing
    startscheduler() #this works
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run() 
else:
    #amazon ec2 apache
    startscheduler() #the function I need to call as soon as the script loads
    application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Don't do that, it is an anti-pattern. You may have several instances of the app running simultaneously. Use something like supervisor.

Comment: I don't think I need something as complex as supervisor for a small app. Is there any alternate option. Just want to know how to run a function automatically in a  webpy app hosted on apache using mod_wsgi.

Comment: Supervisor and Celery are common tools used for this kind of task. I think Celery is somewhat complex but Supervisor is a pretty simple watchdog. Good luck finding something simpler that works well, if you do I would appreciate if you post the solution here.